# simple mysql query working slower than nested Select

Tags: mysql, indexing, nested

I am doing a simple Select from a single table.

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
 `Book_Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Book_Name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `Book_Active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1' ,
 `Author_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Book_Id`),
 KEY `FK_Author` (`Author_Id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_Author` FOREIGN KEY (`Author_Id`) REFERENCES `author` (`Author_Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5947698 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

**table** : book

**columns** :
Book_Id (INTEGER 10) | Book_Name (VARCHAR 100) | Author_Id (INTEGER 10) | Book_Active (Boolean)

I have Indexes on three columns : Book_Id (PRIMARY key) , Author_Id (FK) , Book_Active .

first query :

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE Author_Id = 1 AND Book_Active = 1

EXPLAIN : 
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                   key         key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      book    ref     FK_Author,index_Book_Active     FK_Author   4       const   4488510 Using where
```

second query :

```
SELECT b.* FROM book b 
WHERE Book_Active=1 
AND Book_Id IN (SELECT Book_Id FROM book WHERE Author_Id=1)
EXPLAIN :
id  select_type         table   type            possible_keys       key                 key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             book    ref             index_Book_Active   index_Book_Active   1       const   9369399 Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  book    unique_subquery PRIMARY,FK_Author   PRIMARY             4       func    1       Using where
```

The data statistics is like this :

```
16.8 million books 
10.5 million Book_Active=true
6.3 million Book_Active = false
```

And For `Author_Id=1`

```
2.4 million Book_Active=false
5000 Book_Active=true
```

The first query takes **6.7** seconds . The second query takes **0.0002** seconds

What is the cause of this enormous difference ? is it the right thing to use the nested select query ?

edit: added "sql explain"

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before both queries and post the output of that please.

Comment: If you change the order of execution of both the queries you will get a different result though, the reason being the use of cache memory.

Comment: @SashiKant i strongly oppose. I try it all and several times and in any order. timings never change

Comment: How many different authors do you have?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case: MySQL uses `FK_Author` index (this gives us ~4.5M rows), then it has to match every row against `Book_Active = 1` condition — index cannot be used here.

The second case: InnoDB implicitly [adds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) primary key to every index. Thus, when MySQL executes this part: `SELECT book.* FROM book WHERE Book_Active=1` it has `Book_Id` from the index. Then for the subquery it has to match `Book_Id` with `Author_Id`;  `Author_Id` is a constant and is a prefix of the index; implicitly included primary key can be matched against implicit primary key from `Book_Active` index. In your case it is faster to intersect two indices than to use index to retrieve 4.5M rows and scan them sequentially.

Comment: Why cant book_Active index be used in the first case ?

Comment: Add an index on `(Book_Active, Author_Id)`

Comment: @ypercube would it perform better or should i just turn my queries into nested ones like the example ?

Comment: Which example? I mean add the index and then try the first version.

Comment: im sorry i didnt see your comment in time, BUT I ADDED the index you suggested, and as expected ,it works like a charm, around 0.0001 seconds average. such a straightforward advice , but sometimes inexperience is really a big cloud hiding everything from sight. Would you mind to answer this question , explaining why my index doesnt help and yours helps? so that i can pick it as right answer ?

Comment: as you said, for author_id=1, there are 5000 records with Book_Active=true. Thus MySQL has only to scan 5,000 rows which is much faster than to scan millions of rows.